# Saving Statistics to sqlite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have created a IRC bot for twitch that comes with a couple of features (song request,a queue to join games. Currently I have a table in my database looking like this

```
CREATE TABLE users(id,points,timespent,follower,followed,wMessage);
```

a very simple table(id is the name of user, points are a virtual currency you get for watching the stream that you use for some of the features I mentioned above)timespent is timespent in the channel, follower is if you are a follower, followed is if you have followed once before and wMessage is a welcome message)

I would like it so I can see some statistics on the bot so, statisticslike how many people joined the channel on x year/month/day/hour, how many used the queue feature, how many used y feature on x time. I can only come up with one way to do this but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it:

```
CREATE TABLE queueStats(usedDate DATETIME,timeUsed int);
```

I guess you could even remove the timeUsed and just make a new row each time the feature is used and then count the rows with a "SELECT - WHERE" query. Is this a smart way to do this? The reason I ask is, I am very new with sql databases so I am not really sure of the standard way to do things(if there is such a thing)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a table to record events of interest.  You could have a foreign key referencing the user table.  Getting summary statistics could then be done using an aggregation query ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)).

BTW, I'd recommend explicitly specifying your user id column to be an "integer primary key".  See [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) for why/how.  Basically if you don't you could end up with duplicate rows for user IDs, and also if you don't explicitly specify a primary key field, sqlite creates an extra "row id" column for you.